# Best practice for inserting/updating data in multiple tables at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have two tables in my database, Contacts and Addresses:

**Contacts** : ContactID | AddressID | FirstName | LastName

**Addresses**: AddressID | Address1 | Address2 | City | State | Zipcode

I have a page where you can add a contact. It contains all the information for a contact and an address for a contact. Here's my code for when you submit the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ContactsViewModel viewModel)
{
    //if editing an contact, fetch it; otherwise, create a new one
    Contact contact = viewModel.ContactId == 0
        ? new Contact()
        : _adminRepository.GetContact(viewModel.ContactId);
    TryUpdateModel(contact);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _adminRepository.SaveAddress(contact.Address);
        _adminRepository.SaveContact(contact);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewModel);     // validation error, so redisplay same view
}
```

Now my main concern is that the address is added successfully, but then an error occurs when I try to save the contact, leaving the address in the database with no contact.

What's the best practice here for rolling back any changes if an error occurs?

Comment: what do you do in SaveAddress and SaveContact? do you try to commit to DB? try using Unit of Work

Answer (score 4):

Well that should be **one method, not two**.

If an *Address* is always related to a *Contact* (it seems that way), then you should only have one repository - e.g a *ContactRepository*.

You should have one repository per aggregate root, or in simple terms - a repository for each entity that needs to be retrieved on it's own.

I don't know what `_adminRepository` is, but i think you just just have a `SaveContact(contact)` method.

Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework? If so, both inserts will be done in one transaction (handled by EF), so if one fails, both will fail.

If you start making changes against multiple repositories/aggregate roots, then you will need something like a *Unit of Work*, or a **TransactionScope.**

So it sounds like you need to rethink your repository design a little bit. There should be a generic *Save* method for a single aggregate entity (Contact), not seperate ones for each relation.

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework. My admin repository contains functions for each entity, so there's SaveContact(), SaveAddress, GetAllContacts(), GetAllAddresses(), etc. Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: @Steven - two questions: 1) Can you add an Address without a Contact? 2) Can you add a Contact without an Address? It sounds like the answer is no and no. Is that correct?

Comment: It's actually yes and no :). You can add an address without a contact, but you must add a contact WITH an address.

Comment: Yeah ContactRepository seems a better name +1 for transactionscope

Comment: @Steven - right, then it comes down to if you need to access both a Contact and an Address independendantly (e.g by ID). If you do, then you'll need 2 repositories.

Answer (score 1):

"Unit Of Work" patterns nice and accepted solution for multiple operations on db -or anothers operations also- please read sample from [Faisal Mohamood,
Program Manager, Entity Framework blogs.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TransactionScope() in your repository. Check out [MSDN forum entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/833a2689-a51b-44e9-9527-7437c057102c/). First reply shows a simple example for integrating it into a method. The key is that without it there isn't a way to specifically rollback changes.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to make a single stored procedure to insert both records. You can use TSQL transactions. Using a TransactionScope() would also work, so the decision should probably be based on your data access layer. If you're already using a lot of SPROCs, make make a complex one with a transaction.

If you're using Entity Framework (... the pain!!!!) then a .net TransactionScope() would be better.

Comment: I am using simple dapper for data operations and wanted to implement using plain sql queries (no stored procedures). If i take the second approach i have to make repositories for each and every entity in my DB, in which the code may be more and also i need to unit test all the repositories.